# Android room library version replaced by somehow

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-room

I have a next project structure:

```
+-- 
|     \-- app
|     \-- my-lib
```

To `my-lib` I added dependencies:

```
implementation "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0-alpha02"
kapt "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.1.0-alpha02"
```

I tried to access `@DatabaseView` and found out that it doesn't exists
When I looked in "External libraries" tab in idea, I found that **2.1.0-alpha02** is replaced by **2.0.0-rc01**

I was trying to find where it may come from, but there is no place, where I could add it

I tried `./gradlew clean --refresh-dependencies --debug` and I even couldn't find the mention of **2.1.0-alpha02**
Gradle event doesn't trying to resolve it, but resolves **2.0.0-rc01**:

```
16:08:17.414 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Resolve androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' started
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.414 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService] Build operation root.1.81.85 could not be started (4 worker(s) in use).
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.414 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository'.
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAddCookies] CookieSpec selected: default
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainComponentMetaDataResolver] Attempting to resolve component for androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01 using repositories [/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository, /var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository, /var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository, Google, BintrayJCenter, MavenRepo]
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.jar
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.client.protocol.RequestAuthCache] Auth cache not set in the context
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71 [changing = false]
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository'.
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection request: [route: {s}->https://dl.google.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 0 of 20; total allocated: 0 of 20]
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/m2repository'.
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01 [changing = false]
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71 [changing = false]
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.jar
16:08:17.415 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.conn.PoolingHttpClientConnectionManager] Connection leased: [id: 28][route: {s}->https://dl.google.com:443][total kept alive: 0; route allocated: 1 of 20; total allocated: 1 of 20]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01 [changing = false]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/google/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71 [changing = false]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71 [changing = false]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.apache.http.impl.execchain.MainClientExec] Opening connection {s}->https://dl.google.com:443
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.jar
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01 [changing = false]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Cached meta-data for module must be refreshed: will perform fresh resolve of 'androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01' in 'Google'
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.modulecache.DefaultModuleMetadataCache] Recording absence of module descriptor in cache: org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71 [changing = false]
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading file:/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7/1.2.71/kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.2.71.jar
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.ExternalResourceResolver] No meta-data file or artifact found for module 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71' in repository '/var/local/android-sdk/extras/android/m2repository'.
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository] Cached meta-data for missing module is expired: will perform fresh resolve of 'org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-android-extensions-runtime:1.2.71' in 'Google'
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.repositories.resolver.DefaultExternalResourceArtifactResolver] Loading https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transfer.DefaultCacheAwareExternalResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/jetbrains/kotlin/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime/1.2.71/kotlin-android-extensions-runtime-1.2.71.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor] Build operation 'Metadata of https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom' started
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpResourceAccessor] Constructing external resource metadata: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
16:08:17.416 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.resource.transport.http.HttpClientHelper] Performing HTTP HEAD: https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/androidx/room/room-runtime/2.0.0-rc01/room-runtime-2.0.0-rc01.pom
```

Then I tried to look into dependency three, to understand who might brought it with:

```
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.2.71
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.2.71
|         +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.2.71
|         \--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
\--- android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0-alpha02 -> androidx.room:room-runtime:2.0.0-rc01
     +--- androidx.room:room-common:2.0.0-rc01
     |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
     +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite-framework:2.0.0-rc01
     |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
     |    \--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.0-rc01
     |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
     +--- androidx.sqlite:sqlite:2.0.0-rc01 (*)
     +--- androidx.arch.core:core-runtime:2.0.0-rc01
     |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
     |    \--- androidx.arch.core:core-common:2.0.0-rc01
     |         \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
     \--- androidx.legacy:legacy-support-core-utils:1.0.0-rc01
          +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          +--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01
          |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          |    +--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01
          |    |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          |    \--- androidx.versionedparcelable:versionedparcelable:1.0.0-rc01
          |         +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          |         \--- androidx.collection:collection:1.0.0-rc01 (*)
          +--- androidx.documentfile:documentfile:1.0.0-rc01
          |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          +--- androidx.loader:loader:1.0.0-rc01
          |    +--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          |    \--- androidx.core:core:1.0.0-rc01 (*)
          +--- androidx.localbroadcastmanager:localbroadcastmanager:1.0.0-rc01
          |    \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
          \--- androidx.print:print:1.0.0-rc01
               \--- androidx.annotation:annotation:1.0.0-rc01
```

Module `my-lib` contains only room's dependencies, I don't understand who might force the **2.0.0-rc01**

I tried to force **2.1.0-alpha02**:

```
configurations.all {
    resolutionStrategy {
        force "android.arch.persistence.room:runtime:2.1.0-alpha02"
        force "android.arch.persistence.room:compiler:2.1.0-alpha02"
    }
}
```

But it didn't help me
I re-built project a lot of times with cleaning cache - it also didn't help

Repositories which I use in my project:

```
google()
jcenter()
mavenCentral()
```

- Gradle plugin is **3.2.1**
- kotlin-gradle-plugin is **1.2.71**
- support lib is 28.0.0
- `androidx` is enabled in gradle properties

Anybody faced with something like that?

Answer (score -1):

I think version 2.1.0-alpha02 of Room is only available in the AndroidX apis. Migrate to AndroidX and give it another try.

Comment: 1). `androidx` is enabled in gradle properties
2). look at the packages I posted, they have prefix `androidx` which means it enabled